# How can I implement a abstract class which is derivate from BaseException and ABC at the same time in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, exception, abstract-class

According to develop my application, I need to create an abstract class, which extends BaseException class. In order to do that, I already wrote this code:

```py
import abc

class MyBaseAbstractClass(abc.ABC, BaseException):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bar(self, reference) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

class MySecondaryAbstrClass(MyBaseAbstractClass):
    ...

obj = MySecondaryAbstrClass()
```

By the way, **I expect to get an error in order to not implemented methods.** So I find this solution, its not working though:

```py
import abc

class MyBaseAbstractClass(BaseException, metaclass=abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bar(self, reference) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

class MySecondaryAbstrClass(MyBaseAbstractClass):
    ...

obj = MySecondaryAbstrClass()
```

The error of this implementation is:

> TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

The behavior I expect is like that:

```py
import abc

class MyBaseAbstractClass(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bar(self, reference) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

class MySecondaryAbstrClass(MyBaseAbstractClass):
    ...

obj = MySecondaryAbstrClass()
```

Nevertheless, this partial code is not extended BaseException. How can I have this behavior in my application?

Comment: According to [`Exception` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception): _All user-defined exceptions should also be derived from this class._

Comment: `metaclass=abc.ABC` is wrong - `abc.ABC` isn't a metaclass. The correct metaclass would be `abc.ABCMeta`, but it still won't work anyway because creating abstract subclasses of non-`object` built-in classes has been broken since `abc` was introduced.